# Socket connection to ftp not receiving answers

Tags: c#, sockets, ftp

I'm using C#, Visual Studio 2008, Framework 2.0 for embedded device.

I'm having trouble with the use of a Socket connection to communicate with FTPs.

In the purpose of you guys to help me, I wrote a snippet to explain my troubles...

```
        IPEndPoint endpoint;
        Socket cmdsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(args[0]);
        endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, int.Parse(args[1]));   

        // Connection
        cmdsocket.Connect(endpoint);

        if (cmdsocket.Connected)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type the command to send : ");
                string l_sCommandToSend = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want a timeout to receive ? (Y/N (default))");
                string l_sReceiveTimeout = Console.ReadLine();

                // Sending
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((l_sCommandToSend + "\r\n").ToCharArray());
                cmdsocket.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, 0);
                if (l_sReceiveTimeout == "Y")
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                // Receiving
                byte[] bufferToRead = new byte[512];
                string l_sResponsetext = "";
                int l_iByteReceivedCount = 0;
                while (cmdsocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Receiving...");
                    l_iByteReceivedCount = cmdsocket.Receive(bufferToRead, SocketFlags.None);
                    l_sResponsetext += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferToRead, 0, l_iByteReceivedCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("Bytes Received : " + l_iByteReceivedCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("l_sResponsetext : " + l_sResponsetext);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("This is the answer : " + l_sResponsetext);
            } while (true);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Job done.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Fermeture du socket
        cmdsocket.Close();
        cmdsocket = null;
```

Above is a snippet that :

- Connect to a FTP (I'm using FileZilla Server for tests purposes on my server side)
- Asks the user which command he wants to send
- Asks the user if he wants a Sleep between send and receive (More details later)
- Reads and displays the answer.

I noticed that if I do not use a Sleep between a FTP command and the response, sometimes I don't get a correct response (empty string). 
For example, sending the command "USER Andy" will result in the response "" when no Sleep is set. When the sleep is set to 1 second, I do get the proper answer which is "331 Password required for Andy".

I tried to debug my Socket without talking to a FTP and chose a software like Hercules. Everything is working as expected, my Receive method call just hangs 'til it receives an answer.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an ftp server and at connection firt that i'm doing is:

```
streamWrite.WriteLine("220 'Any text here'");
streamWrite.Flush();
```

try to read first in your client.